# Gtk with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, windows, makefile, gtk, eclipse-cdt

I installed pkg-config
and added pkg-config -cppflags and pkg-config --libs in build setting
please help
I am working on windows 8 and eclipse kepler

```
14:58:32 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Hi_c_gtk ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Hi_c_gtk.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags -MMD -MP -MF"src/Hi_c_gtk.d" -MT"src/Hi_c_gtk.d" -o "src/Hi_c_gtk.o" "../src/Hi_c_gtk.c"
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\Project\workspace1\Hi_c_gtk\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Project/workspace1/Hi_c_gtk/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
gcc: error: pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtkmm-2.4: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option â€˜--cflagsâ€™
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/Hi_c_gtk.o' failed
make: *** [src/Hi_c_gtk.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're trying to integrate GTK with Eclipse on Windows.
I've recently managed to achieve so in both GNU/Linux and Windows environments. On GNU/Linux it was as easy as install pkg-config from the Eclipse marketplace and adding needed libraries.
On Windows tough, I had to configure include paths manually by modifying compiler options. You need to add manually all includes and libraries requested by GTK+ on Project-C/C++ Build-Settings. I used Cygwin's gcc.

The full process is described on http://irkedrants.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/configuring-eclipse-to-compile-gtk.html